# local.xml changing the layout seems to not working

Tags: theme, local.xml

According to: http://blog.belvg.com/use-a-local-xml-file.html
my local.xml is inside my themefolder now and looks like:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="col-left">
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
        <remove name="catalog.product.related" />
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

After the changes I did an:
`rm -Rf var/cache/*` 
but on the frontend, I still can see the compare products block.
My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="widget widget-static-block "> </div>
<div id="" class="col-left sidebar">
  <div class="block block-list block-compare fadeInDown animated" data-animate="fadeInDown">
    <div class="block-title">
    <div class="block-content">
```

Do I need to change the `<reference name="col-left">` to anything else?
If so, how can I find out my valid reference name values? (I assume that's different from theme to theme?)

Comment: use reference="left"  not reference="col-left"..

Comment: Tried it out but without success - the product page still contains the compare block.

Answer (score 1):

Your `local.xml` file should be like this

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
        <remove name="catalog.product.related" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Tried it out and cleaned the cache but nothing changed. Do I need to do anything else but deleting the cache?

Answer (score 0):

```
<layout>

    <default>
    <reference name="right">
            <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />

</reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Not as well - no change at all.
I'm wondering whether I do anything else wrong if the code is right?
`default` is the package? Not the theme?
The structure looks like `app/design/frontend/default/em0121/layout/local.xml`

Answer (score 0):

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.compared" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

See *`layout/reports.xml`*